# Ion Auth - Preventing Simultaneous login

Tags: session, authentication, ion-auth

We have a CI application where we used Ion-Auth as Authentication Library. We have used database for storing sessions.
So far everything works fine. Now, by default Ion Auth allows simultaneous logins for same user from different location. I want to prevent this. As per our client, only one login should be allowed.

1. Is it possible to achieve this, considering abandoned sessions (without pressing logout and closing browser) ?
2. If the issue in (1) above is complex to achieve, can I make a simple check if user is currently logged in./session is active.
   The existing logged_in method does not take any input parameters. So I cant use this method.
   I am assuming solution might be possible with already available library and I  don't need to add extra fields/code to achieve this. 
   Thanks.